# configure SAP Fiori app to be viewed on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, sapui5

​​Hi,

I want to load a Fiori application on Internet Explorer but it is not loading like in Chrome. I have attached the errors that show up.

I have tried to change what is on the index.html page but not luck:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;"/>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Summary Screen</title>

 <!-- Bootstrapping UI5 -->

<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"

  src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"

  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"

  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"

  data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"

  data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"summary": "./"}'

    data-sap-ui-frameOptions="trusted">

  </script>

 <script>

sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {

  sap.ui.require([

    "sap/m/Shell",

    "sap/ui/core/ComponentContainer"

  ], function (Shell, ComponentContainer) {

    // initialize the UI component

    new Shell({

      appWidthLimited: false,

      app: new ComponentContainer({

        height : "100%",

        name : "summary"

      })

    }).placeAt("content");

  });

});
```

Initially it was showing up on internet explorer but then it did not show up anymore.

What changes can I do to be IE compatible?

Thank You!

[image: IE View]

[image: Chrome View]

[image: 403 Error]

[image: 403 Error]

[image: PreProcessorIMPL Error]

Comment: try to click on the third error see.. at `sap.ui.fl.PreprocessorImpl` extension provider. If its SAP standard app, it will not have issues. But if its custom app, and if you have used non-compatible javascript api/methods in your code, this can happen. 
Add your code/runnable link here to get full picture of the app.

Comment: Is this an original unmodified SAP standard app or is it modified or a custom app developed by yourself?
What does it show, when you click on the 3 red error messages (including the “403 errors”)?
I assume, you have a current Internet Explorer version and Cache is cleared?

You say, it was working initially.
Did you change anything afterwards?

In your coding example it says:
`content="IE=edge;"`

Will it work, if you skip the semicolon:
`content="IE=edge"`

Comment: @SAPFioriCrew :  I initially started with a worklist template and modified the worklist view and controller.Yes I have current Internet explorer (IE11) and I cleared the cache. skipping content="IE=edge" did not change anything. I will remove some of the javascript code from the controller and see what happens. Thank You!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [SAPUI5 dropped support for Internet Explorer since v1.88](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/74b59efa0eef48988d3b716bd0ecc933). If this issue still persists, it's not going to get a fix.